# ERROR 6: Unable to set GeoTransform, SAGA binary grids only support the same cellsize in x-y

Tags: gdal-translate

I try to convert a TIF file to a SDAT file using the conversion tool in qgis.

When I execute the gdal_translate command, I get the following message:

"ERROR6:Unable to set GeoTransform, SAGA binary grids only support the same cellsize in x-y
"

Afterwards the SDAT file is created but on a much bigger scale.
What should I do to get the correct conversion?

Comment: please share in details about the conversion process and your tiff data.

Comment: For gdal_translate the x and y resolutions can be set separately https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-tr. Make them be equal and the conversion will succeed.